# Node.JS - Why Buffer not garbage collected in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Minimum test code in Windows 7 and node 10.8.0:

```
for (let i = 0; ; ++i) {
    let buf = new Buffer("1111111111111111111");
    buf = null;
    if (i % 10000 === 0) {
        global.gc();
        console.log(process.memoryUsage().rss);
    }
}
```

and then running with

```
 node --expose-gc .\index.js
```

I can see the rss is keep increasing and the memory allocated on the buffer is not released.
If I just allocate a buffer with a size, for example

```
let buf = new Buffer(10000);
```

The gc will work. Why gc is not working in the test code?

Additional question: It seems that the problem is not existed on the Node Mac OS version, maybe it's a bug on the Windows version?

Comment: Hi, this is probably because your string is too small, and the `gc` decides it's not worth collecting. Try it with a longer string.

Comment: @georg Thanks for your reply! I found this problem when I tried to read a picture in a loop as a Buffer, the memory will cost hundreds of MBs and never got released. This is just a minimium reproduce test code.